# Forgot Password in Codeigniter3

Tags: codeigniter

My code is not work in database.

Here is my model function.please tell me what is wrong in this method since it does not runs in database:

Login_model.php

```
public function forgot_password()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tblmvbsystemusers');
    $this->db->where('sysu_email',$this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('sysu_status','1');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $row=$query->row();
    send_mail($row->sysu_name,$row->sysu_email,'admin_password_help',$row->sysu_email);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check against integer if that way has been stored in DB (i.e. `$this->db->where('sysu_status', 1);`).

Answer (score 0):

please print last executed query
you can use following syntax.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

then copy it and run manually in phpmyadmin.
you will see better result